# Reload specific UITableView cell in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`. I want to update the table data based on selection made. Right now I use `[mytable reloadData]`; I want to know if there is any way where I can just update the particular cell which is selected. Can I modify by using NSIndexPath or others? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

For iOS 3.0 and above, you just have to call :

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

To reload row 3 of section 2 and row 4 of section 3 for example, you'll have to do this :

```
// Build the two index paths
NSIndexPath* indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:2];
NSIndexPath* indexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:3];
// Add them in an index path array
NSArray* indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath1, indexPath2, nil];
// Launch reload for the two index path
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: I am not familiar with index path. Can you please let me in detail.

Comment: NSIndexPath as the name suggests holds an index. An index is made up of 2 components row and section. You can create one with [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(NSUInteger) inSection:(NSUInteger)];

Comment: Each section can have multiple rows. In iPod MP3 player for example you have a section for each letter. Each of this section contains several artist.

I've edited my original code to show you how to do.

Answer (score 6):

You can also get a reference to the UITableViewCell object and change its labels, etc.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = @"Hey, I've changed!";
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for this method of `UITableView`:

```
 - (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```