# How to update a UITableVIewCell without reloading full table

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to refresh a single UITableViewCell in a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448321/is-it-possible-to-refresh-a-single-uitableviewcell-in-a-uitableview)

In a sequence I am updating only a particular object in my list data(NSMUtableArray), once updated its value, To make the GUI update, I was reloaded the full table like below...

```
[table reloadData];
```

It worked fine, However in efficiency point, it is hanging little bit while I am scrolling, Is there any way to update only a particular cell without reload full table?

thanks.

Comment: You can check this if it helps solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040740/reload-spefic-table-cell-ios

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
 - (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

Use this

Comment: it worked, but still the freezing is there while scrolling for this update also..

Comment: Does your cell has images?

Comment: Use lazy Loading for them

Comment: @amar Does "lazy loading" basically mean asynchronous loading?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff yeah its a tech slang which means the loading is lazy and comes after the cell has been loaded.

Comment: Proper answer is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448321/is-it-possible-to-refresh-a-single-uitableviewcell-in-a-uitableview

Comment: @MehulChuahan thats actually wrong implementation we do not need begin and end updates for using reloadRows.It is needed only for insertrow and remove row

Answer (score 9):

You can use this..

```
NSArray *indexPathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
//You can add one or more indexPath in this array...

[tblview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the cell object by -

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

now change its related values as per your object from data array. It should reflect in the table.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, mate. This worked wonderfully for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can reload particular image row using index path .

```
    [mainTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are making a GUI update, it's better to use reloadData rather then using any other methods. reloadData is the best way in your case to update the `UITableView` as it avoids inconsistency. The other thing which you can do is, you can add a condition in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and let execution happen only for the cell which is modified.

Comment: This is wrong. There are several ways to updates parts of a UITableView. reloadRowsAtIndexPaths, reloadSections and reloadSectionsWithIndexTitles will all reload parts of a UITableView.

Comment: @Fogmeister my sentence is incorrect. I meant to say the condition in which Newbee is trying to use it. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just adding one item, and you wish to have that added to the table, you can manually insert it into your UITableView, here's an example:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_directions.count-1 inSection:0];
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:YES];
```

Comment: I already added that object need to updates its value