# TableView in TableViewCell with auto height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

I have a cell like this

The inside `tableView` is not scroll enable, but has dynamic cells, and dynamic `contentSize`

The tableView's height depends on cells

When I use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to auto size for the cell,

```
contentTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

it's not working for the inside `tableView`

it just show Labels of the cell, but not `tableView`

Any Answers? Thanks

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868532/can-i-change-height-of-uitableviewcell-real-time/39870884#39870884) could be useful to your case.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/3901620

Answer (score 0):

First Write this in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```

Set `numberOfLine` property to 0 in `StoryBord`

Set UILable `autolayout` to `Leading` `Trailing` `Top` `Bottom` from `SuperView`

Hope it will work...

For Detail Description Refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)