# Dynamic TextView height in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I'm having TextView inside my TableView and its height has to be increased according to content.
I'm doing it by this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    textView.delegate = self
    textView.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

}
extension TableViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
  func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let currentOffset = tableView.contentOffset
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    tableView.setContentOffset(currentOffset, animated: false)
  }
}
```

TableView are having static cells. Have given Constraints to the TextView properly. My main concern over here is the delegate of textView is not getting called. I have added breakpoint to check it.

Comment: Hopefully, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868532/can-i-change-height-of-uitableviewcell-real-time/39870884#39870884) might be useful to your case...

Comment: @AhmadF But my delegates are not getting called.

Comment: Well, that's another story :) make sure that everything is connected as it should...

Comment: What is the name of your ViewController ?

Comment: @NhatDinh TableViewController

Comment: Why need to use extension? Why dont you just push your uitextviewdelegate in your viewcontroller directly

Comment: @NhatDinh Tried w/o extension but same result.

Comment: Did you declare UITextViewDelegate as delegate of your vc like this : class yourvc, UITextViewDelegate {}

Comment: Yes I did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When manually setting the text of a UITextView with code, the textViewDidChange: method does not get called. (If you have your text view's delegate set, it will get called when the user edits it, though.)

One possible workaround would be to manually call textViewDidChange: anytime you edit the text. For example:

```
textView.delegate = self
textView.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
self.textViewDidChange(self.textView)
```

Kind of a hackish way of doing it, but it gets the job done

Hope this help you.

**Edit**

try this it's work for me

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    textView.delegate = self
    textView.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    self.textViewDidChange(self.textView)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.item == 1{//****Or index of your textView****
        return textView.contentSize.height;
    }
    return 70

}

}

extension TableViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        tableView.reloadData()
       }
}
```

**Update**

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    textView.delegate = self
    textView.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    self.textViewDidChange(self.textView)
    tableView.reloadData()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.item == 0{//****Or index of your textView****
        return textView.contentSize.height;
    }
    return 70

}

}

extension TableViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Comment: By this my delegate is getting called by height of tableview did not increase.

Comment: Ok i found it. you cell not changing size because the textView is not change frame but it's contentSize as it's contain a scrollView.

Comment: I've edited my answer. please let me know if it works for you

Comment: I cannot assign heightForRowAt index to the textView height only. I will be having other stuff too in my other sections of my static TableView. Is there any alternate way?

Comment: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if indexPath.item == 1{//****Or index of your textView****

            return textView.contentSize.height;

        }
        return 70
        
    }

Comment: I works not fully. I can see upto 3 lines in my TextView but other is still not visible.

Comment: I make another update of my answer. please make a copy past of this code and tell me if works for you.

Comment: Still same. Upto 3lines

Comment: here a screen shot of my test : 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz7VLJsUViniblV2UjhUb1NfMWM

Comment: Can you share the zip ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134066/discussion-between-ben-messaoud-mahmoud-and-nitesh).

Comment: Ok I found the problem 
In StoryBoard select your TextView -> go to Attributes Inspector -> enable Scrolling on you textView. 
always use my last version of code