# Unable to add consistent height and padding. between dynamic tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dynamic, tableview

Im trying to implement a tableview that has cells with a product image on the left side and a listing of various product details such as price, title, etc. to the right of the image, however, I have been having trouble with setting up the appropriate spacing/padding between the cells. I want each cell to have some white space between them. Here is an image showing what i have so far, and what the issue is.

[TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVPXP.png)

I am using a stackview as a container for the labels with the product details, and am implementing the dynamic row height feature:
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Everything seems to work great except wajjhen the stackview height is smaller than the imageview height. I can't get the spacing to show in that scenario. I have tried everything for the past 2 days, and it is driving me crazy. Take it easy on me guys as I am an Android guy :)

**All I want is for the I want the separators of tableview cells to have a bit of space between either the top and bottom of the imageview or the stackview(whichever is taller/higher).**

I have attached a SS of the storyboard to show the layouts and constraints. Please let me know if any more information is need.

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuBG7.png)

Comment: Why not get rid of the UITableControl? Use nested UIStackViews? The "substack" is horizontal, containing your single product views (image and details), with the "main stack" being vertical, containing a list of products?

Answer (score 0):

for adding consitent spacing to your cell better way is to treat your **each item as a section** because you can set spacing easily between sections by creating a header view between section. 
So logically if you have 10 objects than you will be having **10 section** with **each section have only one row**.

1.Each section with only one row

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
```

2.Number of section is equal to count array of items

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return array.count 
    }
```

3.Set Hieght for spacing/header view

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10 
    }
```

4.create your header view and customise it

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {      
       if let view = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView{
      view.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have no problem with setting the appropriate height for each cell (if you have, you might want to check this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868532/can-i-change-height-of-uitableviewcell-real-time/39870884#39870884)), I suggest to let each cell on a section instead adding them in the same one.

**Technique:**

By default, if you are not implementing [number​Of​Sections(in:​)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614860-numberofsections), it returns `1`. You should:

- implement it and let it returns the number of array data source -for example- (instead of doing it in [table​View(_:​number​Of​Rows​In​Section:​)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614931-tableview)).
- Let `table​View(_:​number​Of​Rows​In​Section:​)` returns `1`. Each section will has only one cell.
- After that, the trick is to add a header view for the sections (with a clear background color) with desired height, the height will be the margin between the section (cells in your case). You should achieve this by implementing:

[table​View(*:​view​For​Header​In​Section:​)*](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview) and [table​View(:​height​For​Header​In​Section:​)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614855-tableview).

The code will be similar to:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    // ...

    // MARK:- UITableViewDataSource
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell-ID")

        // note that you should read from 'indexPath.section' instead of 'indexPath.row'
        let currentObejct = dataSource[indexPath.section]
    }

    // MARK:- UITableViewDelegate
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        // here, you can customize the header
        // or your case want to let it clear...
        let margin = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 20.0))
        margin.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        return margin
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20.0
    }

    // ...
}
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving the Fruit Image a top and a bottom constraint but they must be >= so it doesn't mess your auto layout

[image: what it looks like in size inspector]

And your constraints will probably look like this

[image: constraints]

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and responses, but I decided to go with this one as it was the easiest to implement, and works perfectly. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: Almost. But this causes the stackview to become stretched out when it is shorter than the image.

Answer (score 0):

3 days later, I finally found a solution I am content with, albeit it is quite janky, but at this point(3 days of dealing with this issue), I don;t really care. I am posting my solutuion in case it helps anyone in the future.

I ended up pinning a view to the tableviewcell with a minimum height of 130 to contain the imageview and stackview. Since I know the minimum height of the tableviewcells is 120, 130 gave a padding of 5 on the top and bottom. I attached the screenshot of my storyboard:

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCuym.png)
[TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V59mN.png)